# Resource not found exception for ShapeableImageView using vector?

Tags: android, imageview, filenotfoundexception, android-vectordrawable

I am using ShapeableImageView in my XML as

```
 <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_unread_msg"
        />
```

I am getting Resource not found exception when I run the app on OS 5 and 6

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_unread_msg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700f7
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2850)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2732)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:74)
   at com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView.<init>(ShapeableImageView.java:96)
   at com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView.<init>(ShapeableImageView.java:92)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/$ic_unread_msg__0.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f07000b
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2960)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2909)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:439)
   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1605)
   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1584)
   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateInternal(VectorDrawable.java:666)
   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:571)

Caused by org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #9: invalid color state list tag gradient
   at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:217)
   at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:201)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2956)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2909)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:439)
```

This is my vector image

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="14dp"
android:height="14dp"
android:viewportWidth="14"
android:viewportHeight="14">
<path android:pathData="M7,0L7,0A7,7 0,0 1,14 7L14,7A7,7 0,0 1,7 14L7,14A7,7 0,0 1,0 7L0,7A7,7 0,0 1,7 0z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient
            android:endX="7"
            android:endY="14"
            android:startX="7"
            android:startY="0"
            android:type="linear">
            <item
                android:color="#FF63D8FF"
                android:offset="0" />
            <item
                android:color="#FF6397FF"
                android:offset="1" />
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
</vector>
```

Can't figure out why the crash is happening?

Comment: maybe the `gradient` cause it?

Comment: Can you try `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_unread_msg"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/ic_unread_msg"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to Sandi's comment

Replacing `android:src` with `app:srcCompat` works